# SQL join involving table having “fieldname” and “fieldvalue” columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables for an auction site. I need to return records from the "listings" table that match geo-related search criteria, which will be passed as follows:

```
province_id = 2
district_id = 1,4
suburb_id = 5,6
```

Note, this comma-delimation comes from a checkbox group in the search form, where user can select multiple provinces, suburbs and/or districts for their search.

**listings**

```
    record_id   title       
    ----------------------
    2231        Ford Mustang
    2232        Nissan GTR
    2233        Chev Camaro
    2234        Plymouth Roadrunner
    2235        Dodge Charger
```

**listing_special_fields**
(related to listings on listing_id = listings.record_id)

```
    record_id   listing_id   fieldname      fieldvalue
    -----------------------------------------------
    1231        2232         province_id    2
    1232        2232         district_id    4
    1233        2232         suburb_id      1
    1234        2233         province_id    2
    1235        2233         district_id    4
    1236        2233         suburb_id      6
    1237        2234         province_id    2
    1238        2234         district_id    4
    1239        2234         suburb_id      5
```

**provinces**

```
    record_id     province
    ----------------------
    1             Northland
    2             Auckland
    3             Waikato
```

**districts**
(related to provinces on province_id = provinces.record_id)

```
    record_id     province_id   district
    ------------------------------------
    4             2             Auckland City
    5             2             Franklin
    6             2             Hauraki Gulf Islands
```

**suburbs**
(related to districts on district_id = districts.record_id)

```
    record_id     district_id   suburb
    ------------------------------------
    1             4             Arch Hill
    5             4             Avondale
    6             4             Balmoral
```

According to the given search parameters, I should get the following output:

**listings**

```
        record_id   title       
        ----------------------
        2233        Chev Camaro
        2234        Plymouth Roadrunner
```

The query should contain joins on the provinces, districts and suburbs tables. Normally it would be straightforward if the listing_specials_fields table had columns named "province_id", "district_id" and "suburb_id" instead of "fieldname" and "fieldvalue".

Comment: You have not correctly named the keys. You have used record_id in most of the tables. Please specify primary keys and foreign keys correctly.

Comment: That is how the primary keys are named for every table in the database. I'm stuck with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PIVOT` to get your expected result. Here is the query for SQL Server:-

**Query**

```
Select Listings.record_id, Listings.title FROM 
(
    select ListingId, fieldId, fieldValue  FROM listing_special_fields
) AS BQ
PIVOT
(  
    MAX(fieldValue)
    FOR fieldId IN ([province_id], [district_id], [suburb_id])
) PV
INNER JOIN Listings ON Listings.record_id = PV.ListingId
WHERE PV.province_id IN (2)
    AND PV.district_id IN (1, 4)
    AND PV.suburb_id IN (5, 6)
```

**Result**

```
order_id          title
  2233         Chev Camaro         
  2234         Plymouth Roadrunner
```

**UPDATE**

MySQL Solution Here:

```
Select Listings.record_id, Listings.title from Listings
INNER JOIN
( Select  
    ListingId,
    MAX(
       case when fieldId = 'province_id' then fieldValue else null end
    ) AS province_id,
    MAX(
       case when fieldId = 'district_id' then fieldValue else null end 
    ) AS district_id,
    MAX(
       case when fieldId = 'suburb_id' then fieldValue else null end
    ) AS suburb_id
  from listing_special_fields
  group by ListingId
) AS PV ON PV.ListingId = Listings.record_id
WHERE PV.province_id IN (2)
   AND PV.district_id IN (1, 4)
   AND PV.suburb_id IN (5, 6)
```

Comment: I have never used pivor before, thanks. Is this for mySQL? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry, It's my mistake. The solution is for **SQL Server**.

Comment: No worries. What a shame. Seems like a very easy solution. I'll google mysql equivalent

Comment: @user460114, check the **MySQL** solution

Comment: Mashedi, how would I alter the query to return the NAMES of the provinces, districts and suburbs as well as their IDs? e.g. to get "Auckland" from the districts table, would that involve joining to the districts table? Where would I include that join?